# ArrayList shows all results from database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, arraylist

I want to get one single row from mysql db. But my program prints all rows from db. I'm not sure what is wrong. Could you help me?

```
public class ScreenBalance {

// show all records
public static ArrayList<String> showOnScreenBalance() throws Exception {
    LoginVerification.login();

    try {
        Connection con = ConnectionDB.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ClientID, Money FROM BankDB.Info");

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.print("\nID\t\tAmount\t\n");
        while (result.next()) {
            System.out.print(result.getString("ClientID"));
            System.out.print("\t");
            System.out.print(result.getString("Money"));
            System.out.print("\t");
            array.add(result.getString("Money"));
        }
        System.out.println();
        return array;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Below is my second class which I was hoping that selects one row. But it doesn't work properly. I'm typing clientID + client password, so why my method 'showOnScreenBalance' doesn't see it?

```
public class LoginVerification {

private static boolean loggedIn = false;

    public static void login() throws Exception {

        System.out.println("ATM Machine v 1.0, Welcome user.");
        if(loggedIn){
            //do nothing, user already logged in
            return;
        }

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter USER ID:");
    String userId = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter PIN CODE:");
    String pass = input.nextLine();

    try {
        Connection con = ConnectionDB.getConnection();
        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Info WHERE ClientID = ? AND ClientPass = ?";

        PreparedStatement posted = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        posted.setString(1, userId);
        posted.setString(2, pass);
        ResultSet resultSet = posted.executeQuery();
        resultSet.next();
        int rowCount = resultSet.getInt(1);

        if (rowCount == 1) {
            loggedIn = true;
            System.out.println("LOGIN SUCCESSFUL");
            Helper.showMainMenu();

        } else {
            loggedIn = false;
            System.out.println("#LOGIN UNSUCCESSFUL, WRONG LOGIN OR PASSWORD");

            System.out.println("\nTry again? \n1) yes \n2) no [quit]");
            int choice = input.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1) {
                login();
            } else {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
        con.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Your query selects all rows in the table. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Your second class won't see the (local) variables in your first class, because you're not passing them to the second class. You could make your method `showOnScreenBalance(String userid)` and use that in the where clause to select the correct user's balance.

Comment: wow thank you, it's what i'm looking for :) could you please correct my showOnScreenBalance method? i have troubles to do it by myself

Comment: Actually the easiest way would be probably to make your `login()` return the `userId`. Then you can get it at `String user = LoginVerification.login();`. I won't write the code for you, since it's **your** homework.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define which row of the database table to be printed. To do that, you can define a WHERE clause in your sql statement.

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ClientID, Money FROM BankDB.Info WHERE some_condition" );
```

eg:

```
PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement("SELECT ClientID, Money FROM BankDB.Info WHERE ClientID='some_value'" );
```

For the number of results to be 1, the WHERE condition must also designed such a way.(Only one row with such column value can be there).Otherwise there is no way for the program to know what is your expected result.

Hope it helps :)